# Exiting or quiting game in Andengine

Tags: android, android-intent, andengine

I tried to exit game via finish() and System.exit(0) .But finish() just exiting on activity not all game.System.exit(0) is restarting not exiting from all game.What can I do exit from all game? It shouln't run in background!

Answer (score 2):

finish() should work for you.

If it is leaving some of your other activities open behind the GameActivity then you just need to make sure that all of your activies are calling finish() when they are done (after you've called startActivity() if you are moving along to a new Activity). That way whenever you call finish() on the GameActivity there should be nothing left on the Stack below it.

Comment: My game: It starts with a splash screen(3 sec) as StartActivity.And afer 3 seconds MenuActivity starts...The MenuActivity has a button for exit..When you press exit button, finish() is running.And StartActivity opening.Not exiting from all game!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());` to exit apk.

Comment: Or System.exit(0);  Especially if you have multiple scenes etc. I believe Kadir had something wrong in his code if it did not work.